# How to convert a single quoted number or integer like '265' to actual integer like 265 using parseInt?

Tags: javascript

I am giving code like this

But getting the output as Nan

```js
var totalTicketOpenCountFromWidget = sunriseReportObj.getIncidentDsrTotalTicketOpenCount(sunriseReportTestData.totalOpenTicketsWidgetName);
console.log("totalTicketOpenCountFromWidget :", totalTicketOpenCountFromWidget);
var totalTicketOpenCountFromWidgetIntVal = parseInt(totalTicketOpenCountFromWidget);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the way to ensure `totalTicketOpenCountFromWidget` would be a number you can do:

```
totalTicketOpenCountFromWidgetIntVal = parseInt(totalTicketOpenCountFromWidget);
```

or

```
totalTicketOpenCountFromWidgetIntVal = parseInt(totalTicketOpenCountFromWidget, 10);
```

the 10 aims to decimal.

Read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

or the easier way:

```
totalTicketOpenCountFromWidgetIntVal = +totalTicketOpenCountFromWidget;
```

Also, you can wrap your conversion in a `try ... catch` block to handle the response if `totalTicketOpenCountFromWidget` is not a number. Read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Comment: Radix 10 is the default: `parseInt(...)` is the same as `parseInt(..., 10)`

Comment: Right, totally right